# jboss tools installation error in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I've installed Java 7, Eclipse indigo and downloaded Jboss AS 7.1.1. Now i would like to install jboss tools using eclipse marketplace, but I'm receiving these dependency conflicts every time...

I'm getting the errors mentioned in the unsuccessful installations tab located here

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: JBoss Central 1.0.0.v20120307-1926-H67-Beta1 (org.jboss.tools.central.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.v20120307-1926-H67-Beta1)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.4.0.20110615-0550 (epp.package.jee 1.4.0.20110615-0550)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Equinox Java Authentication and Authorization Service (JAAS) 1.0.200.v20100503 (org.eclipse.equinox.security 1.0.200.v20100503)
    Equinox Java Authentication and Authorization Service (JAAS) 1.1.1.R37x_v20110822-1018 (org.eclipse.equinox.security 1.1.1.R37x_v20110822-1018)
    Equinox Java Authentication and Authorization Service (JAAS) 1.1.0.v20110502 (org.eclipse.equinox.security 1.1.0.v20110502)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.4.0.20110615-0550 (epp.package.jee 1.4.0.20110615-0550)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.4.0.20110615-0550]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.4.0.20110615-0550 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20110615-0550)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.7.0.v20110530-9gF7UHNFFt4cwE-pkZDJ7oz-mj4OSEIlu9SEv0f]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.v20110530-9gF7UHNFFt4cwE-pkZDJ7oz-mj4OSEIlu9SEv0f (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.7.0.v20110530-9gF7UHNFFt4cwE-pkZDJ7oz-mj4OSEIlu9SEv0f)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.security [1.1.0.v20110502]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JBoss AS Core Plug-in 2.3.0.v20120321-1339-H91-Beta2 (org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core 2.3.0.v20120321-1339-H91-Beta2)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.equinox.security 1.1.1
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JBoss Central 1.0.0.v20120307-1926-H67-Beta1 (org.jboss.tools.central 1.0.0.v20120307-1926-H67-Beta1)
    To: bundle org.jboss.tools.project.examples 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JBoss Central 1.0.0.v20120307-1926-H67-Beta1 (org.jboss.tools.central.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.v20120307-1926-H67-Beta1)
    To: org.jboss.tools.central [1.0.0.v20120307-1926-H67-Beta1]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Project Examples 1.2.1.v20120320-2046-H78-Beta2 (org.jboss.tools.project.examples 1.2.1.v20120320-2046-H78-Beta2)
    To: bundle org.jboss.tools.seam.core 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Seam Tools 3.3.0.v20120302-2019-H81-Beta1 (org.jboss.tools.seam.core 3.3.0.v20120302-2019-H81-Beta1)
    To: bundle org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core 0.0.0
```

Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

I too faced this issue.  I could resolve the issue by first updating the Eclipse (Help --> Check for Updates) and then install the jboss tools.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the JDK 6? I had the same problem with JBoss 7, Indigo and JDK 7. Switching back to JDK 6 and wiping out all my other JDK instances worked for me. Make sure that you update indigo (as admin or root) as well.

Hope that helps a little.